# Conditionally binding or ignoring a value in do notation

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads

As a learning project I am currently trying to build a parser for the ELF file format in Haskell. Elf binary files have a section called a program header, and this header contains a word dedicated to flags. The program header contains two fields for flags: one for 64 bit flags, one for 32 bit flags, in non-sequential order.

Like so:

```
data ProgramHeader =
    ProgramHeader {
        getSegmentType :: SegmentType
      , get64SegmentFlags :: SegmentFlag
      , getOffset :: Offset
      , getVirtualAddress :: Address
      , getPhysicalAddress :: Address
      , getFileSize :: Size
      , getMemorySize :: Size
      , get32SegmentFlags :: SegmentFlag
      , getAlignment :: Either Word32 Word64
    }
```

And parsing looks like this:

```
parseProgramHeader :: WordSize -> Endianness -> Get Program
parseProgramHeader wordsize en = do
  st <- parseSegmentType
  flags64 <- parseSegmentFlag
  offset <- parseVariant wordsize en
  virtualAddress <- parseVariant wordsize en
  physicalAddress <- parseVariant wordsize en
  fileSize <- parseVariant wordsize en
  memorySize <- parseVariant wordsize en
  flags32 <- parseSegmentFlag
  a <- parseVariableWord wordsize
  return $ ProgramHeader st flags64 offset virtualAddress physicalAddress fileSize memorySize flags32 a
```

Now I'd like to be able to merge those two `SegmentFlag` fields into a single one as such:

```
data ProgramHeader =
    ProgramHeader {
        getSegmentType :: SegmentType
      , getSegmentFlags :: SegmentFlag
      , getOffset :: Offset
      , getVirtualAddress :: Address
      , getPhysicalAddress :: Address
      , getFileSize :: Size
      , getMemorySize :: Size
      , getAlignment :: Either Word32 Word64
    }
```

But, I would still need to parse the flags word twice (in each corresponding position), keeping only the relevant one.

My intuition is that it means I need to bind the parseSegmentFlag value only for the corresponding wordsize; while still calling parseSegmentFlag if it's not the case, but discarding the value.
In pseudocode:

```
parseProgramHeader :: WordSize -> Endianness -> Get Program
parseProgramHeader wordsize en = do
  st <- parseSegmentType
  if wordsize == Bit64
      then
        do flags <- parseSegmentFlag
      else
        discard $ parseSegmentFlag
  [...]
  if wordsize == Bit32
    then do flags <- parseSegmentFlag
    else do discard $ parseSegmentFlag
```

Now I have absolutely no idea how I could perform that elegantly in Haskell. Any ideas? Pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: In the pseudocode, what's `ws`? `wordsize`?

Comment: It is Indeed :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option, just leave the code as you have it, then at the end pick out the version that is relevant, i.e.

```
...  -- as before
let flags = case ws of
                Bit32 -> flags32
                Bit64 -> flags64
return $ ProgramHeader st flags ...
```

(I use `case` instead of `if` because if you happen to add another case, you'll get a warning here instead of falling through to whichever branch you picked as the default)

Comment: How have I not thought of that! Thanks a lot @luqui :-)